# how to set up a vagrant working directory

Tags: command, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualhost

Hope this isn't a foolish question.

I'm attempting to set up a virtual machine in virtualBox using Vagrant.

I'm following the documentation here:

http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/project_setup.html

of the three commands, the first two are successful but when I try and run the command `vagrant init` i get the following in my command prompt:

```
C:\Windows\System32\vagrant_geting_started>vagrant init
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

The working directory for Vagrant doesn't exist! This is the specified working directory:

C:/Windows/System32/vagrant_geting_started
```

I'm unsure of the issue as I've checked that directory and that file path exists.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `vagrant init PROJECT_NAME`, replacing 'PROJECT_NAME' with your projects name?